# What marine animals exhibit deep hibernation/aestivation?

Tags: zoology, metabolism, marine-biology

Do marine animals exhibit deep hibernation/aestivation as land-based creatures do?

If not, Why?

Comment: Turtles and frogs do, if you classify them as "marine" animals...

Answer (score 3):

Fish are [ectothermic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ectotherm), and so, by definition, cannot hibernate because they cannot actively down-regulate their body temperature or their metabolic rate. However, they can experience decreased metabolic rates associated with colder environments and/or low oxygen availability (hypoxia) and can experience dormancy. For example, epaulette sharks have been known to stay dormant for long periods without oxygen ([reference](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hibernation#Dormancy_in_fish)) Turtles in freshwater lakes have been known to hibernate by burying themselves in mud ([reference](http://teacher.scholastic.com/activities/explorer/oceanlife/main.asp?template=meet_explorer&article=interview_frank)). The mechanism through which turtles can experience several months of hypoxia or anoxia is explained in [this paper](http://icb.oxfordjournals.org/content/27/1/59). The Antarctic fish (Notothenia coriiceps) has been found to be able to activate and deactivate their metabolic processes independent of body temperature and hence enter a state of dormancy similar to hibernation through metabolic suppression ([reference](http://www.plosone.org/article/info%3adoi/10.1371/journal.pone.0001743)).